# code is not returning the expected value?

Tags: c#

code not returning expected result. should be 15

```cs
using System;

namespace Delegate
{
    public class Program
    {
        private char[] OnePointValues = { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'l', 'n', 'r', 's', 't' };
        private char[] TwoPointValues = { 'd', 'g' };
        private char[] ThreePointValues = { 'b', 'c', 'm', 'p' };
        private char[] FourPointValues = { 'f', 'h', 'v', 'w', 'y' };
        private char[] FivePointValues = { 'k' };
        private char[] EightPointValues = { 'j', 'x' };
        private char[] TenPointValues = { 'q', 'z' };
        string word = "joke";

        public int WordScoreCheck(string word)
        {
            int score = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
            {

                for (int j = 0; j < OnePointValues.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (word[i] == OnePointValues[j])
                    {
                        score = score + 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        score = score + 0;
                    }
                        for (int k = 0; k < TwoPointValues.Length; k++)
                        {
                            if (word[i] == TwoPointValues[k])
                            {
                                score = score + 2;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                score = score + 0;
                            }
                                for (int l = 0; l < ThreePointValues.Length; l++)
                                {
                                    if (word[i] == ThreePointValues[l])
                                    {
                                        score = score + 3;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        score = score + 0;
                                    }
                                        for (int m = 0; m < FourPointValues.Length; m++)
                                        {
                                            if (word[i] == FourPointValues[m])
                                            {
                                                score = score + 4;
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                score = score + 0;
                                            }
                                                for (int n = 0; n < FivePointValues.Length; n++)
                                                {
                                                    if (word[i] == FivePointValues[n])
                                                    {
                                                        score = score + 5;
                                                    }
                                                    else
                                                    {
                                                        score = score + 0;
                                                    }
                                                        for (int o = 0; o < EightPointValues.Length; o++)
                                                        {
                                                            if (word[i] == EightPointValues[o])
                                                            {
                                                                score = score + 8;
                                                            }
                                                            else
                                                            {
                                                                score = score + 0;
                                                            }
                                                                for (int p = 0; p < TenPointValues.Length; p++)
                                                                {
                                                                    if (word[i] == TenPointValues[p])
                                                                    {
                                                                        score = score + 10;
                                                                    }
                                                                    else
                                                                    {
                                                                        score = score + 0;
                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                        }
                                                }
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                }
            }
            return score;
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var Program = new Program();
            int p=Program.WordScoreCheck("joke");
            Console.WriteLine(p);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your nesting of the for loop are wrong.  the one point , two point, three point should be in parallel.  Instead the two point is a child of the one point. The three point is a child of the two point.

Comment: This is too complicated. You should use Dictionary<char, int>, put all the characters and their values in there, and just do a lookup and add the value for each character of the test word, without all these ifs and elses. It can be a simple loop or a LINQ statement.

Comment: thank you so much!! codes working well now

Comment: This is not a good question to begin with. You're saying that it's not giving you the desired result of 15, but you haven't explained why it's the desired result, or even what the program is supposed to do. Sure, you can figure it out by going through the code, but you shouldn't leave the reader to figure out the question.

Second, do you have to use such an elaborate error prone method? You can do this with like two lines of code using `LINQ` and a `Dictionary`. Even without `LINQ` this can be done more elegantly.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a `LINQ` example just in case you didn't know how to do it this way.

Instead of individual arrays, you can use a `Dictionary` for this purpose, of type `Dictionary<int, List<char>>`. The `Key` holds the numerical 'point' values, and against each of them you list the characters that belong in that group.

```
private static Dictionary<int, List<char>> PointValues = new Dictionary<int, List<char>>
{
    { 1, new List<char>() { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'l', 'n', 'r', 's', 't' } },
    { 2, new List<char>() { 'd', 'g' } },
    { 3, new List<char>() { 'b', 'c', 'm', 'p' } },
    { 4, new List<char>() { 'f', 'h', 'v', 'w', 'y' } },
    { 5, new List<char>() { 'k' } },
    { 8, new List<char>() { 'j', 'x' } },
    { 10, new List<char>() { 'q', 'z' } }
};
```

Then, using `LINQ`, you get the `Key` for each character in your word. Simply iterate through the characters in the word, then see if the dictionary contains it, and if so, retrieve the `Key` which is the point value. Then add it to your score.

```
private static int WordScoreCheck(string word)
{
    var score = 0;

    foreach (var ch in word)
    {
        score += PointValues.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value.Contains(ch)).Key;
    }

    return score;
}
```

Call it like this:

```
static void Main()
{
    var word = "joke";
    Console.WriteLine("Word: {0}, Score: {1}", word, WordScoreCheck(word));
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Agree with all of the comments above regarding the posture of the question.

There are some basic things to consider:

The point of the program as far as I can understand is sort of like a Scrabble point system calculation.

The trade off to make is to decide whether to sacrifice space for clarity simplicity:  For this example, you don't lose much by preparing your data ahead of time (sacrifice space).  A simple array can solve this  data abstraction problem:

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] points = new int[] { 1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 8, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 8, 4, 10};
            foreach (string s in args)
            {
                int sum = 0;
                foreach (char c in s)
                {
                    if (Char.IsLetter(c))
                    {
                        sum += points[Char.ToLower(c) - 'a'];
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Points for {0} = {1}", s, sum);
            }
        }
```

Explanation:

Each character is worth a certain point value.
Each character is  in the range of 'a' to 'z'
Make an array of the preset point values per character.

De-reference the point value by using the character to index into the array of values.  Accumulate sum.

Eg: `points[0]` is the point for `a`
`points[3]` is the point value for `d`

Good luck.

Comment: Careful with `char.IsLetter`... it will match more than just `'A'` to `'Z'` and `'a'` to `'z'`. For example, a string with `'é'` will cause an `IndexOutOfRangeException`. It would be better to test those two ranges explicitly because the array only has 26 elements for those exact letters.

Comment: Yea, that's right.  I didn't bother worrying about that.  Another test for the ordinal value of the character might be better.  Good catch.